# Allowing outbound connection via UFW

Tags: ufw

I'm having trouble configuring UFW's 'default deny outgoing' setting. How do I add exceptions to this?

Example:

```
sudo ufw enable
sudo ufw default deny outgoing
sudo ufw allow to 91.189.94.40
sudo ufw allow from 91.189.94.40
sudo ufw allow 80
sudo ufw status verbose
wget http://91.189.94.40:80
```

The connection still gets blocked.

Comment: try systemctl restart ufw

Comment: no luck with the above ^^

Answer (score 0):

You want to allow traffic out. This is what I had to do:

```
sudo ufw allow out 80
```

Does that work?